# What is this user-input regex checking for? /^[^<">]*$/

Tags: regex

This regex is used to check some user input:

```
/^[^<">]*$/
```

What is it checking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's checking for double quotes (`"`) and angle brackets (`<>`).

```
/^[^<">]*$/
```

`/^` means the start of the string.
`[^<">]` means *not* `<`, `"`, or `>`.
`*` means zero or more of the previous expression.
`$/` means the end of the string.

So it's checking whether the input consists of zero or more characters, none of which are `<>"`.

Answer (score 10):

It's checking for a line (possibly empty) that doesn't contain <, > or ".

Comment: +1.  In multiline mode this is what it'll do. If it's not in multiline mode it'll search the entire string to ensure it doesn't contain any of these characters.

Answer (score 2):

It ensures that the input contains no `<` `"` or `>` characters.

`^` at the beginning matches the literal beginning of the string.

`[^<">]*` matches 0 or more characters that ARENT one of the three: `<">`.

`$` at the end matches the literal end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

That none of these characters appear on the line: < > "

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[^<">]*$/
```

To be clear: it does not match any string that contains <, >, or ".

It will match anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Any string that doesn't contain <"> characters.

Answer (score 0):

Matching a string against this RegEx will return FALSE if any double-quotes or brackets exist in the string.  If none exist, or the string is empty, it will return TRUE.

Answer (score -2):

This is probably a simple regex being used to check for an xml element with an attribute.